# Configuring transaction across multiple resources using spring framework?

Tags: spring, transactions, distributed-transactions

I understand the fact that a transaction that spans multiple transactional resources is called a global transaction.

Question 1:
Is this just an another name for distributed transaction or is that something different?

Question 2:
Have gone through spring's documentation on Transaction Management.
What i could infer from that is
a. JTA is purely designed for distributed transactions.
b. Only through EJBs and EJB CMT, we could enforce distributed transactions.
c. If EJBs, then it mandates an Application Server and indirectly JNDI too.

What is Spring's counterpart to facilitate global/distributed transactions?

Question 3:
If we don't want to go with an application server with JTA capability,
should we be using Atomikos / JOTM like standalone Transaction managers to enforce global transactions?

Question 4:
A simple usecase of updating Table A in DB_1 (MySql) and Table B in DB_2 (Oracle) under a single transaction:
What is Spring's answer to this usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. a) No, not every transaction will be distributed, only if more than one resource is involved. The TM handles the management of the transactions executed on the involved resources
3. b) No, there are transactionsmanagers usable outside ejb-servers like atomikos, bitronix,... but I am not sure what you mean by enforce, as I wrote earlier, distributed transactions are used when necessary.
4. c) yes
5. d) [Springs counterpart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html)
6. if you want to use transactions on multiple resources at the same time yes.
7. you define two datasources in a way, that they let a TM handle their resources. Both MySql and Oracle provide XA-Datasources which allow it to handle distributed transactions. You define a TM and make it possible to annotate your beans with Transaction Attributes. There are many tutorials out there which show how this can be done.

Additional remarks:

1. Meanwhile transactions are also included in the CDI-Spec. So you can also use CDI.
2. Handle the distributed transactions wisely. The two way commit makes it almost impossible to set a reasonable transaction timeout. There are development-sites where distributed transactions only are used between one SQL-DBMS-Resource and one JMS-Resource if necessary.

Comment: Thanks aschoerk for your time and efforts in answering that question.